# In which cases does HttpResponse.SupportsAsyncFlush return false

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, httpcontext

There is a property on [`HttpResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) object named [`SupportsAsyncFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.supportsasyncflush.aspx) which returns the value of the [`HttpWorkerRequest.SupportsAsyncFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.supportsasyncflush.aspx) property according to MSDN. However, when I look at the `HttpWorkerRequest.SupportsAsyncFlush` property through a decompiler, I can see that it's already returning `false` which makes me think that I am missing something.

As the `HttpWorkerRequest` is an abstract class, I think that the hosting layer (IIS, etc) implements this class and overrides the `HttpWorkerRequest.SupportsAsyncFlush` virtual property if needed? if this is the case, in which cases does `HttpContext.Response.SupportsAsyncFlush` return false under IIS?

Comment: I was reading the source as well, wonder if this is a placeholder for future functionality maybe?

Comment: @rickschott as the `HttpWorkerRequest` is an abstract class, I guess the hosting implementation of this overrides the property if needed. Do you know which class is the IIS implementation for this?

Comment: @rickschott I guess it is `IIS7WorkerRequest` class which is internal.

Comment: No clue, it probably just a hook for modules then.  I doubt you'll get a clear answer on this one.

Comment: @rickschott and `IIS7WorkerRequest.SupportsAsyncFlush` always returns `true`. I should have a look at the call stack.

Comment: This is a really good question BTW!

Comment: @rickschott yeah, it's definitely `IIS7WorkerRequest` for IIS and internal `HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification` gets the `IIS7WorkerRequest` as a parameter. I hope someone from the ASP.NET team will clear this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All IIS 7.0+ hosts override this property to return true.  If a custom host is being used, then the host will have to go out of its way to override the property to return true.  For example, the Cassini host doesn't support async flushes so doesn't override the property.

tl;dr: If you're running in IIS or IIS Express, you are guaranteed that this will return true.

Answer (score -1):

its returns true if asynchronous flush operations are supported. otherwise it will returns false.

Comment: No way! really? :) I understand that part and I'm interested in which cases that happens.